# Upgraded eclipse and testng on eclipse and now my project is not running

Tags: eclipse, testng

I had my project in perfect condition and was able to right click on my testng.xml file and Run-As TestNG Suite with no errors.

Now after upgrading both eclipse and testng via Eclipse>Help>Check for Updates, I get a whole bunch of errors when I try to run the same project

Here is just the top portion of the errors I have:
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1213)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTXfImpl.getXfId(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.getStyleAt(StylesTable.java:225)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellStyle(XSSFCell.java:481)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellStyle(XSSFCell.java:64)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(DateUtil.java:320)

What is going on? Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing what the exception actually is, but if I were you, I would just revert Eclipse to the previous version.